# Extent Report: Add Class Name Method Name to fail test

Tags: cucumber-jvm, extentreports

I"m running Cucumber selenium extent report in my test project. I wonder how to add class name + method name into extent report for pass/fail test results. Below is my code:

```
    @CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/Feature",
        glue = {"Step_Definitions"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
    })

        public class TestRunner {
            private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;
            private ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
            private ExtentReports extent;
            private ExtentTest logger;

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());

        htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/report/Test-Report.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports ();
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        extent.setSystemInfo("Host Name", "MyTest");
        extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", "SIT");
        extent.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Peter Wong");

        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Test Report");
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "dataProvider")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }
  /*  
    @Test
    public void passTest(){
        logger = extent.createTest("passTest");
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
        logger.log(Status.PASS, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Test Case Passed is passTest", ExtentColor.GREEN));

         try {
            logger.fail("Pass Details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot.png").build());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LogManager.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

  */

    @AfterMethod
    public void getResult(ITestResult result){
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getThrowable() + " - Test Case Failed", ExtentColor.RED));
        }
        else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            logger.log(Status.SKIP, MarkupHelper.createLabel(result.getName() + " - Test Case Skipped", ExtentColor.ORANGE)); 
        }
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        extent.flush();
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is it add the capture method name at @Test? How about using Cucumber
   to achieve this?

   2. What is the best design approach to integrate extent report with Cucumber runner class?

Please help. Hope someone who can really help me on this.

[image]

Comment: You can add Method argument to the AfterMethod testng hook. But this will give you the name of the test method inthe runner itself? Are you looking for step details of the feature file?

Comment: Refer to this for integrating cucumber and extent https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter

Comment: No, I want to add the Test Class Name + Method